# In PHP, does suppressing error output of a function (via @) affect performance if no error occurs?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

Like most of our code base, our mysql handling functions are custom built.

They work very well and include a number of logging forks.

A simplified version of our query execution function looks like this:

```
if(!$result=mysql_query($query)){
    file_put_contents(QUERYLOG,'Query '.$query.' failed execution');
}
```

This is overly simplified, but you get the basic idea: If queries fail, they will be logged to a separate query log.

This is a great way of keeping track of any queries that need to be looked at.

My question is as follows:

With the above, the tiny problem is that if a query fails both our query log, AND our php log will be stamped with the error as a mysql_query (... or mysql_connect, mysql_select_db, etc ...) will produce a php error.

What we want to do is surpress the php error via:

```
.... $result=@mysql_query($query ....
```

So, as far as the question goes:

Does using the @ error suppression mechanism in php cause any performance impacts if no error is produced? Or does it only affect performance if an error is produced?

I know I know, micro optimization, but as you can guess, or query execution function is used millions of times a day, so even a small performance hit is worth examining.

Comment: No, it's not necessarily worth examining.  If one version were a microsecond faster (and i expect that it's far less than that), you're talking about *a few seconds a day*.  That's less than 0.1%.  Worry about whether the code is correct, not whether it's less-than-0.1% faster.

Comment: I disagree. While we could spend days debating this (and im sure there are countless SO questions regarding this) even a 0.1% impact is worth examining. My point of view on the matter is that 20 or 30 of these micro optimizations equal one 'macro' optimization. Which seeing as our code base is about 3-4 years old now, are very hard to come by. I would guess that we will never agree on the matter, so point taken, thank you.

Comment: And besides, learning about how php's error suppression mechanism internals work, alone, is worth the 3 minutes it took me write the question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

made a little "research"

```
$s = microtime(true);
$a = array('1','2');
$b = $a[1];
echo microtime(true)-$s;
```

gives `1.1205673217773E-5`
and if i use `$b = @$a[1];` i get a bit more: `1.5974044799805E-5`

so: yes, there is a difference, but no, you should not bother.